# Query not working when inside while loop

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

```
<?php
function acceptOrder(){
    $conn = myConnect();
    $qty=$_POST['order_qty'];
    $ctr=$qty;
    while($qty!=0){
        $sql = "UPDATE ingredients SET ingredient_qty=ingredient_qty-2 WHERE ingredient_id='1'";
        $qty++;
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 
    if($result){
        $str="Successfully ordered Product.";
        header("Location:../admin/cook.php?success-msg=".$str);
    }else{
        echo "Error updating your user. ".mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}
```

why does not the query work when I try to put it in a while loop new to PHP

> Notice: Undefined variable: sql in C:\xampp\htdocs\lol\controllers\ProductController.php on line 121
>
> Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query in C:\xampp\htdocs\lol\controllers\ProductController.php on line 121
> Error updating your user.

Comment: I like how if that `while` loop ever starts, it will never finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only executing the SQL after the loop...

```
while($qty!=0){
        $sql = "UPDATE ingredients SET ingredient_qty=ingredient_qty-2 WHERE ingredient_id='1'";
        $qty++;
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 
    }
```

So move the mysqli_query line inside the loop.  Although...

Your loop doesn't seem to do much other than continually update the qty '-2'.  You probably don't need the loop at all!

```
function acceptOrder(){
    $conn = myConnect();
    $qty=$_POST['order_qty'];
    $sql = "UPDATE ingredients SET ingredient_qty=ingredient_qty-$qty WHERE ingredient_id='1'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 
    if($result){
        $str="Successfully ordered Product.";
        header("Location:../admin/cook.php?success-msg=".$str);
    }else{
        echo "Error updating your user. ".mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}
```

Although you should look into using prepared statements and bind variables as well.

**Update**:  If you just wanted to use a loop to update a set of ingredients..

```
$ingredients = array( 1 => 2, 2=>1, 3=>1);
foreach ( $ingredients as $id => $qtyIng ) {
        $updateQty = $qtyIng * $qty;
        $sql = "UPDATE ingredients SET ingredient_qty=ingredient_qty-$updateQty WHERE ingredient_id='$id'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 
    }
```

The `$ingredients` array stores the id of each ingredient and the quantity of each.  So id 1 would be for eggs and it uses 2...

The `foreach` goes through the list of ingredients, multiples it by the quantity you need and then the update uses this quantity and the $id of the ingredient to update the correct item.

Comment: Im putting it in a loop since the idea was what if order_qty was more than one because the original idea for the query was to update multiple columns and I was only trying to query 1 column because I just wanted to figure out the while loop

Comment: You update multiple columns in one statement.  If you wanted to use a while loop, I'll add another example.

Comment: order_qty is the quantity of how much "Dois Noodles" is ordered, and when the admin inputs 2 it updates the columns in the ingredients table taking away 4 eggs, 2 Ramyun Noodles and 2 Spam(because 1 Dois Noodles= 2 eggs, 1 Ramyun Noodles and 1 spam). The idea was to automatically update the ingredient table once something was ordered. I'm sorry if I sound unclear or not understandable.

Comment: That would be better handled by 3 separate update statements, these could be done in a loop - I will update the answer with a suggestion.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time on this @Nigel Ren, I also noticed about the operator I already changed it a long time ago.

Comment: Adding some of this information would have made your original question clearer and would show what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: Only problem left is that it doesn't update the table. Whenever I try to use "variables" inside the sql statement or query it never updates in the table that's what I noticed.

Comment: Just make sure the I'd value matches your data

Comment: Finally working but no matter what value Input it reduces all the data to 0. I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: Check what `$updateQty` is for each item, make sure it's a reasonable value.